# which credentials to pass creating user session in magento web services?

Tags: php, web-services, magento

I am learning php with magento web services.

As I know that before connecting the magento web services we need to create the session.

apiuser = windows login or magento database login or something else
apikey = windows login or magento database login or something else

Which credentials should use let me know?

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to first setup a web services user and role in the backend of Magento. The user will have a username (the *apiuser*) and a password (the *apikey*).

You can figure out how to setup these with this documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-web-services (it says it's for the Magento Go platform but this should also apply to what you are trying to do.)